# Comparing in python list

Tags: python

I am new in python and hope you could help me solve this problem and I am using python 3.4.

I have a list that contain word,either positive or negative, and it's frequency

This is the original list:

finalSentiment = [('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'positive'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ... ('dem','positive')('dem','negative')]

What i am trying to do is to calculate number of positive and negative for each word from the list that I have.
So that if the number of negative is higher, the word is negative.
Then I can come out with a new list like: 
eg: newList = [('hijacked','negative'),('left','negative'), . . .]

a) I try using the num = Count(finalSentiment).most_common()[:50] function and came out with the new  list as below.

> num =  [(('hijacked', 'negative'), 302), (('left', 'negative'), 88), (('one', 'negative'), 79), (('befo', 'negative'), 72), (('radical', 'negative'), 70), (('tcot', 'negative'), 70), (('tanker', 'negative'), 55), (('like', 'negative'), 47), (('right', 'negative'), 36), (('oil', 'negative'), 26), (('hijacked', 'positive'), 22), (('pirates', 'negative'), 21), (('people', 'negative'), 21), (('terrorist', 'negative'), 21), (('loony', 'negative'), 18), (('morons', 'negative'), 18), (('get', 'negative'), 17), (('account', 'negative'), 12), (('flag', 'negative'), 11), (('time', 'negative'), 10), (('angry', 'negative'), 9), (('like', 'positive'), 8), (('day', 'negative'), 8), (('know', 'negative'), 8), (('dem', 'negative'), 7), (('tanker', 'positive'), 7), (('long', 'negative'), 6), (('left', 'positive'), 6), (('driver', 'negative'), 6), (('one', 'positive'), 6), (('got', 'negative'), 6), (('tcot', 'positive'), 5), (('radical', 'positive'), 5), (('befo', 'positive'), 5), (('pirates', 'positive'), 3), (('live', 'negative'), 3), (('oil', 'positive'), 2), (('time', 'positive'), 2), (('pay', 'negative'), 2), (('none', 'positive'), 1), (('people', 'positive'), 1), (('morons', 'positive'), 1), (('long', 'positive'), 1), (('account', 'positive'), 1), (('mt', 'negative'), 1), (('got', 'positive'), 1), (('day', 'positive'), 1), (('loony', 'positive'), 1), (('know', 'positive'), 1), (('fathers', 'negative'), 1)]

What I want to do is to compare the word frequency either positive or negative is higher.
So, if negative is higher I want to create a new list that contain the word and negative.

eg: [('hijacked','negative'),('left','negative'), . . .]

Each word will only have either positive or negative in the list.

What I have try to is I try to access each of the item in the list using for loop.

for item in num:

```
    unique_word = item[0]
    temp = unique_word[0]
    temp1 = unique_word[1]
    frequency = item[1]
```

but I cant figure out how to manipulate the data after I access it.

b) I use counter() function and come out with this list:

cnt = Counter()
for word in finalSentiment:
    cnt[word] += 1
print(cnt)

Result : Counter({('hijacked', 'negative'): 302, ('left', 'negative'): 88, ('one', 'negative'): 79, ('befo', 'negative'): 72, ('tcot', 'negative'): 70, ('radical', 'negative'): 70, ('tanker', 'negative'): 55, ('like', 'negative'): 47, ('right', 'negative'): 36, ('oil', 'negative'): 26, ('hijacked', 'positive'): 22, ('pirates', 'negative'): 21, ('terrorist', 'negative'): 21, ('people', 'negative'): 21, ('morons', 'negative'): 18, ('loony', 'negative'): 18, ('get', 'negative'): 17, ('account', 'negative'): 12, ('flag', 'negative'): 11, ('time', 'negative'): 10, ('angry', 'negative'): 9, ('like', 'positive'): 8, ('day', 'negative'): 8, ('know', 'negative'): 8, ('dem', 'negative'): 7, ('tanker', 'positive'): 7, ('got', 'negative'): 6, ('left', 'positive'): 6, ('one', 'positive'): 6, ('driver', 'negative'): 6, ('long', 'negative'): 6, ('radical', 'positive'): 5, ('befo', 'positive'): 5, ('tcot', 'positive'): 5, ('pirates', 'positive'): 3, ('live', 'negative'): 3, ('time', 'positive'): 2, ('pay', 'negative'): 2, ('oil', 'positive'): 2, ('mt', 'negative'): 1, ('loony', 'positive'): 1, ('morons', 'positive'): 1, ('long', 'positive'): 1, ('got', 'positive'): 1, ('sadly', 'negative'): 1, ('day', 'positive'): 1, ('none', 'positive'): 1, ('fathers', 'negative'): 1, ('account', 'positive'): 1, ('malaysia', 'negative'): 1, ('right', 'positive'): 1, ('people', 'positive'): 1, ('know', 'positive'): 1, ('look', 'positive'): 1})

The problem I have now is to compare as example the word 'hijacked', the number of negative is higher so in the new list, 'hijacked' should be 'negative such that: 
eg: newList = [('hijacked','negative'),('left','negative'), . . .]

c) OR maybe I should calculate number of positive and negative on my own instead of using the most_common() function or counter().
My problem to calculate the number of positive and negative is because there are multiple word in the list. If the word is only 'hijacked' with positive and negative attached to it I think I can solve the problem.

Comment: May want to read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[(('hijacked', 'negative'), 302), (('left', 'negative'), 88), (('one', 'negative'), 79), (('befo', 'negative'), 72), (('radical', 'negative'), 70), (('tcot', 'negative'), 70), (('tanker', 'negative'), 55), (('like', 'negative'), 47), (('right', 'negative'), 36), (('oil', 'negative'), 26), (('hijacked', 'positive'), 22), (('pirates', 'negative'), 21), (('people', 'negative'), 21), (('terrorist', 'negative'), 21), (('loony', 'negative'), 18), (('morons', 'negative'), 18), (('get', 'negative'), 17), (('account', 'negative'), 12), (('flag', 'negative'), 11), (('time', 'negative'), 10), (('angry', 'negative'), 9), (('like', 'positive'), 8), (('day', 'negative'), 8), (('know', 'negative'), 8), (('dem', 'negative'), 7), (('tanker', 'positive'), 7), (('long', 'negative'), 6), (('left', 'positive'), 6), (('driver', 'negative'), 6), (('one', 'positive'), 6), (('got', 'negative'), 6), (('tcot', 'positive'), 5), (('radical', 'positive'), 5), (('befo', 'positive'), 5), (('pirates', 'positive'), 3), (('live', 'negative'), 3), (('oil', 'positive'), 2), (('time', 'positive'), 2), (('pay', 'negative'), 2), (('none', 'positive'), 1), (('people', 'positive'), 1), (('morons', 'positive'), 1), (('long', 'positive'), 1), (('account', 'positive'), 1), (('mt', 'negative'), 1), (('got', 'positive'), 1), (('day', 'positive'), 1), (('loony', 'positive'), 1), (('know', 'positive'), 1), (('fathers', 'negative'), 1)]
newd=dict(x)
for i in newd.keys():
    if i[1]=="negative":
        z=list(i)
        z[1]="positive"
        z=tuple(z)
        if z in newd.keys():
            if newd[z]<newd[i]:

                print i
```

You can try something like this by making a dictionary out of the list and comparing keys and values.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I think some of the word now is missing because I only have this : ('loony', 'negative')
('time', 'negative')
('like', 'negative')
('pirates', 'negative')
('got', 'negative')
('morons', 'negative')
('hijacked', 'negative')
('account', 'negative')
('befo', 'negative')
('tanker', 'negative')
('oil', 'negative')
('left', 'negative')
('tcot', 'negative')
('day', 'negative')
('one', 'negative')
('radical', 'negative')
('long', 'negative')

Comment: @AhmadZaki that's because some of the keys dont have positive attached to them